# How can I force a client to update its IP address in SCCM?

Tags: powershell, sccm

I am testing some networking issues with a machine that i need to move through the organization, this make the machine to change its ip.

SCCM need to update this ip (highlighted in the picture) in order to contact the machine, the problem is that my environment is so large that it takes 4 or more hour to run a full discovery of the machines.

There is a faster way to update the ip of the machine via powershell or another tool?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The computer's IP address will update on its next Discovery Data Collection cycle.  You can force this to happen by running this command on the client:

```
WMIC /namespace:\\root\ccm path sms_client CALL TriggerSchedule "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003}" /NOINTERACTIVE
```

This is the list of all available actions:

Application Deployment Evaluation Cycle: `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000121}`

Discovery Data Collection Cycle: `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003}`

Hardware Inventory Cycle: `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}`

Machine Policy Retrieval and Evaluation Cycle: `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000021}`

Software Inventory Cycle: `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002}`

Software Metering Usage Report Cycle: `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000031}`

Software Updates Deployment Evaluation Cycle: `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000108}`

Software Updates Scan Cycle: `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000113}`

Windows Installer Source List Update Cycle: `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000032}`

Comment: A much easier way of running any scans on collections or individual devices is by using the Right-Click Tools by Now Micro. It's a simple install, then re-launch the console, and you're good to go. http://www.nowmicro.com/recast/recast-rct-free/

Comment: I definitely agree!

Comment: I don't understand how running right click tools which are Server side, will allow to trigger a Discovery Data Collection Cycle if the client's IP address it not the (good) updated one yet... Only triggering the action locally can help

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the SCCM database is the last discovery data update. It's not live data. It doesn't use this to locate the machine to run a new discovery when you use utilities like right click tools; it uses DNS.

As long as DNS is functioning and reporting correct data, it will be able to contact the machine and send discovery requests, and retrieve that data back into SCCM databases.